# Assembly Language [ EMU 8086]

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have this
mov cx,12345d

Now i want to check if the last 3 digits of this number are for example 111 in binary

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"AND" the value with "111" (binary) to clear all other bits and then compare the result with "111" (binary).

It's been more than a decade since I did some x86 assembly, but it should look something like this:

```
AND CX, 111b
CMP CX, 111b
JE found
; whatever happens when it is not found
JMP end
found: 
; whatever happens when it is found
end:
; the end
```

Comment: can you explain me a little bit more , i'm new to assembly language

Comment: Thanks mate i will try

Comment: You certainly do not want to OR it. You want to AND it.

Comment: @A.Design A small explaination: For each bit in the two inputs `AND` sets the corresponding bit in the output if and only if both input bits are true. This way all bits in cx get dropped except for the last 3 bits which are set in `111b`. If one of those 3 bits in cx wasn't set it won't be set in cx after the `AND`. So the only way CX contains `111b` is if the last 3 bits of CX we set before the `AND`. [Bit masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) might be of interest to you.

Comment: no different than other languages, and, or, xor, are present in many/most languages, nothing special about assembly here, it also contains a bitwise and.   in C   if(x&7)==7) then the bits are all ones.   x=x&7;  if x==7 then  and cx,7  cmp cx,7  je or jne